# how to omit charging deposit if the same item selected between specified time period?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on car rental system. Currently I allow users choose the same addon items as many times as they wish. Deposit charge and price per day will occur for each items chosen.

Now I want to add some condition. If the same item chosen between the specified time period and the quantity is one, deposit charge will be omited from second item onwards. How do I achieve this please?

For instance,
specified time period=11-09-2014  to  17-09-2014

Item 1 chosen from 11-09-2014 to 12-09-2014.Deposit $20 and $50 price per day charged.
item 1 chosen again from 13-09-2014 to 16-09-2014 and the quantity is 1.Now I want to omit the deposit from being charged ,instead just charge the price per day $50 for the second item.

Can anyone help please?

This is my array

```
$_SESSION['info'][]=array('c_id'=>$car_id,'addon_id'=>$addon_id,'date_c'=>$date_c,'date_d'=>$date_d,'item_type'=>$item_type,'quantity'=>$qty,'services'=>$services);
```

And this is how I call them

```
             foreach($_SESSION['info'] as $info=>$in)
               {


                   $info;
                   echo $in['addon_id'];

                 }



 I tried:
    if(in_array($in['addon_id'],$_SESSION['info']))
    {
    echo'exist';
    }


    I tried:
    if(array_key_exist($in['addon_id'],$_SESSION['info']))
    {
    echo'exist';
    }

    I tired:
    if ( count($in['addon_id']) > count(array_unique($in['addon_id'])) ) 
    {
     EXECUTE CODE
    }
```

It display exist for all item entered the array. What I want is, if for first time a value enters array then must mark new, if more than once the same value enters then mark exist.

Comment: Just have your rental object detect if it already has that extra marked against it and if so return failue/throw an exception. Or you could use a property for the extra(IE `$rental->has_item1($bool_item1_taken)`)

Comment: @scragar but how do I check if it's already has extra marked?

Comment: You should load the car into an object that has the list of addons, then check the list with either a loop: `public function HasAddon($selected_addon){ foreach($this->addons AS $addon){ if($addon == $selected_addon) { return TRUE; } } return FALSE; }` or with an index check if you're loading actual properties: `public function has_addon1(){ return $this->selected_feature1 !== NULL; }`

Answer (score 0):

I simply used comparison operators like <= and >= to compare the dates and it worked!